# How to add values of a mask image as one of the classification classes

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I have performed supervised classification on GEE in the Russian Lena Delta to map different vegetation classes using sentinel 2 images (BUT i had to mask out the water and sandbank pixels) to improve the classification results.

However, I would like now (after the classification) to include the sand and water masks as additional classes in the classified layer (for visualization reasons) but somehow i cannot achieve this. Does anyone have any idea how?
beloow is my work flow

```
var roiDelta = ee.FeatureCollection("*********"),
    HC_Heim = ee.Image("*******"),
    geoms = 
    /* color: #98ff00 */
    /* shown: false */
    ee.Geometry({
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            126.4953564453125,
            72.3816136993482
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                126.09710205078125,
                72.19780053250948
              ],
              [
                126.676630859375,
                72.20787438492015
              ],
              [
                126.654658203125,
                72.44551315285538
              ],
              [
                126.061396484375,
                72.43639841991575
              ]
            ]
          ],
          "geodesic": true,
          "evenOdd": true
        }
      ],
      "coordinates": []
    });

var roi = geoms.buffer(25000); // to test on smaller subset
// var roi = roiDelta;

// cloud maks
function cloudMask(image){
  var QA60 = image.select('QA60');
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
}

// compute ndvi across images in collection
function getNDVI(image){ 
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

// load Sentinel2 data for summer 2018
var S2dat = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
        .filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-09-15')
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .map(cloudMask).map(getNDVI);


//Global surface water
var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater')
            .select('occurrence')
            .unmask(0);



var WaterMask = gsw.lt(60);

var ndviComp  = S2dat.qualityMosaic("NDVI").clip(roi);
var SandMask  = ndviComp.select("NDVI").gt(0.21).updateMask(WaterMask);

var ndviPalette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'];

var ndviCompMask = ndviComp.updateMask(WaterMask).updateMask(SandMask);



//classification

var samplepoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geoms, 2000, 0, 10);
//Map.addLayer(samplepoints, {}, 'sample points', false);

var tablePts = HC_Heim.reduceRegions(samplepoints, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
var tablePtsID = ee.FeatureCollection(tablePts.map(function(feat){
  var id = ee.Feature(feat).get('id');
  return ee.Feature(feat).set("Class_ID", id);
}));


// This property of the table stores the land cover labels.
var bands = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','B8','B9','B10','B11','B12', 'NDVI'];
var label = 'first';

// Overlay the points on the imagery to get training.
var training = ndviCompMask.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  'collection': tablePts,
  'properties': [label],
  'scale': 10
});
//print(training);


var trained = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(training, label, bands);
print(trained);

var classified = ndviCompMask.select(bands).classify(trained).clip(roi);
// print(classified);

//Map.addLayer(classified,
             {min: 0, max: 11, palette: [
                  '68ab5f', '1c5f2c', 'a3cc51', '82ba9e', 'ccb879',
                  'dcd939', 'b5c58f', 'b8d9eb', 'af963c', '6c9fb8',
                  'f19414', '202cff']}, 'classes', false);

/// legend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to provide complete, running scripts in your question, Still keep them as short as possible to get your point across. It makes it easier and faster to answer.

One way to add back in a class for the water is to do the below. It replace the classification mask with one that includes water pixels, then assign those water pixels a class. Repeat this process for sand.

```
var withWater = classification
  // Add back the water pixels
  .mask( 
    classification.mask().where(waterMask.not(), 1)
  ) 
  // Water pixels get class value 5
  .where(waterMask.not(), 5)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/793e02acb9100648cbfffc09f4c9e01f